# Passing PFObject to ios application with pubnub

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, pubnub, pfobject

I want to send PFObject from my Parse.com cloud with PubNub. I send PubNub message with json PFObject and receive it in my IOS app.

`JSON.stringify(pfObject)`

But i don't know how can I deserialize it in my IOS app as do the PFCloud methods.

There is a solution or not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Either:

just pass the objectID between the page & the app... the data is gotten from parse

---

#### Or:

send the json like you do now and then build the PFObject from that

1. send the json  / receive it on iOS
2. parse it on IOS using `NSJSONSerialization`
3. use the resulting `NSDictionary` to make a new PFObject

   call `+ (PFObject *)objectWithClassName:(NSString *)className dictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;`

Comment: With this solution, after received the message PubNub , I'll have to make a request to Parse.com to get the PFObject . I try to avoid it...

Comment: You're awesome ! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you a lot !